# How to open another page in HTML5 Builder

Tags: rad, html5builder

Sorry for my very simple question, I'am new to HTML5 Builder.

I'm developing a simple database editing application (to add or remove some advertisments on site, only for system administrator), and I want to make it using HTML5 builder (I hope, it will be fast and simple).

On button click on main page ("Add record" button), I need to open another page with data fields (advinfo.php).

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to **redirect** to the target page. How to do so will depend on the language you want to use.

If you want to use the **JavaScript** OnClick event of the button:

```
function Button1JSClick($sender, $params)
{
    ?>
    //begin js
    window.location = "advinfo.php";
    //end
    <?php
}
```

If you want to use the **PHP** OnClick event (the standard event):

```
function Button2Click($sender, $params)
{
    header("Location: advinfo.php");
}
```